# Dynamically create class and its properties from a csv file columns

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a csv file with 3 columns. Sometimes the csv will have 4 or 5 columns. That we cannot predict. Whatever it may be, I want to create a class with properties based on the columns in the csv file at run time. I have created a class like this.

```
      public class ModalClass : DynamicObject
      {
       private Dictionary<string, object> _propbag = new Dictionary<string, object>();
       private object _outputvals = null;
    
    public DateTime Date
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public Dictionary<string, object> PropertyBag
    {
        get
        {
            return _propbag;
        }
        set
        {
            _propbag = value;
        }
    }


    public object OutPutValue
    {
        get
        {
            return _outputvals;
        }
        set
        {
            _outputvals = value;
        }
    }

    public int Count
    {
        get
        {
            return PropertyBag.Count;
        }
    }

    public override bool TryGetMember(GetMemberBinder binder, out object result)
    {
        string name = binder.Name;
        return PropertyBag.TryGetValue(name, out result);
    }

    public override bool TrySetMember(SetMemberBinder binder, object value)
    {
        PropertyBag[binder.Name] = value;
        return true;
    }

    public void AddProperty<TTValue>(string key, TTValue value = default(TTValue))
    {
        PropertyBag[key] = value;
    }

    public void AddProperty(string typeName, string key, object value = null)
    {
        Type type = Type.GetType(typeName);

        if ((type = value as Type) != null)
        {
            PropertyBag[key] = Convert.ChangeType(value, type);
        }
        else
        {
            if (value.GetType().ToString() == "Null")
            {
                PropertyBag[key] = null;
            }
            else
            {
                PropertyBag[key] = value;
            }

        }

    }
}
```

And in my c# class, i have the code for reading csv file and trying to generate the class properties dynamically.

```
private List<ModalClass> ReadCSV()
    {
        List<ModalClass> lstValues = new List<ModalClass>();

        CsvConfiguration csvConfiguration = new CsvConfiguration(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
        {
            HasHeaderRecord = true,
            Delimiter = ",",
            PrepareHeaderForMatch = args => args.Header.ToUpper(),
            UseNewObjectForNullReferenceMembers = true
        };

        CsvReader csv = new CsvReader(File.OpenText("C:\\Users\\sunil\\Desktop\\MyCSV.csv"), csvConfiguration);
        csv.Read();
        csv.ReadHeader();

        while (csv.Read())
        {
            string d0 = csv.GetField<string>("DATETIME");
            double? d5 = csv.GetField<double?>("SECONDS");

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(d0))
            {
                DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse(d0, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).AddMilliseconds(d5.HasValue == true ? d5.Value : 0);

                Dictionary<string, double> item = new Dictionary<string, double>();

                foreach (string str in columns)
                {
                    var d1 = csv.GetField<double>(str);
                    item.Add(str, d1);
                }

                ModalClass spData = new ModalClass();
                spData.Date = dt;
               
                foreach (KeyValuePair<string, double> entry in item)
                {
                    //adding datatype, column name and the value
                    spData.AddProperty("double", entry.Key, entry.Value);                        
                }

                lstValues.Add(spData);
            }
          
        }

        return lstValues;
    }
```

This will be used in the constructor of viewmodel like shown below :

```
        List<string> columns = new List<string>();
        columns.Add("AA"); // suppose these are the 4 columns in the csv file.
        columns.Add("CC");
        columns.Add("XC");
        columns.Add("QWS");

        Data = new ObservableCollection<ModalClass>(ReadCSV());
```

But the Data doesnt have "AA" or "CC" or "XC" or "QWS" properties !!!
How I can create a class and properties dynamically in C# ? [here i use WPF app].

Just added : How to bind the propertbag with the xaml properties ???

Here is the below screen shot of Data collection :

[image: Data Collection object]

And I dont know what to do here.

```
  private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ViewModel vm = new ViewModel();
        foreach (var str in vm.Data)
        {
            LineSeries lineSeries = new LineSeries();
            lineSeries.ItemsSource = new ViewModel().Data; // works
            lineSeries.XBindingPath = "Date"; // works
            lineSeries.YBindingPath = "str[0]"; // PropertyBag["AA"] here what to do ??
            
            chart.Series.Add(lineSeries);
        }
        this.DataContext = vm;
    }
```

This is for plotting a graph. I want to generate the Y axis datas as per the column header values in the csv file. In the YBindingPath the value will be PropertyBag["AA"]. I dont know how to do it.

Comment: Just a note, the `string typeName` argument of the second AddProperty overload is completely useless. The whole method makes no sense at all. Besides that, it isn't clear what you mean with "*the Data  doesnt have ... properties*". There should be key/value pairs in the PropertyBag property.

Comment: @Clemens After the ReadCSV method, it should contain the dynamically added AA, CC, XC, QWS properites. But we cannot find it in there in the Data collection

Comment: The properties must be present at compile time. They are not dynamic. Replace "AA" with "PropertyBag["AA"]" if you're adding binding paths to `columns`?

Comment: @mm8 I updated the question. Please read it.

Comment: Debug your code to find out whether PropertyBag contains the desired elements. Besided that, the DynamicObject implementation allows to bind directly to those named properties.

Comment: @mm8 Did you notice the DynamicObject implementation?

Comment: @Clemens: Not really. My point is that you can bind directly to the dictionary of values as demonstrated in my answer.

Comment: @mm8 Then you should at least also tell that implementing DynamicObject is redundant. And it still does not help OP to find out why their expected properties aren't there. They are probably just parsing their CSV file incorrectly.

Comment: In case you are expecting that columns for the dynamic properties will be generated automatically, that won't happen. You have to create them manually.

Comment: The simplest way out is to use a `DataTable`.

Comment: Is there a particular reason you've chosen not to use a datatable?
If you really really want a dictionary then you could consider dr wpf's observable dictionary.  http://drwpf.com/blog/2007/09/16/can-i-bind-my-itemscontrol-to-a-dictionary/

Answer (score 0):

> How to bind the propertbag with the xaml properties ???

Bind to the `PropertyBag` property and specify the key of the dynamic "property", e.g.:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding PropertyBag[AA]}" />
```

**View Model:**

```
public class ViewModel
{
    private Dictionary<string, object> _propbag = new Dictionary<string, object>()
    {
        { "AA", "value..." }
    };

    public Dictionary<string, object> PropertyBag
    {
        get
        {
            return _propbag;
        }
        set
        {
            _propbag = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I cannot hard code the column names. It will vary in each csv file.

Comment: Then you should define the bindings programmatically.

Comment: This will not work as expected

Comment: What will not work? Create the bindings? You can't define dynamic binding paths in markup so you don't have much of a choice I am afraid. Or what do you mean/ask?

Comment: I have updated the question for your reference. Please have a look at it